# Creating a js function to measure time range

Tags: javascript, jquery, time

I want to show open/close badge when the shop is open/closed accordingly.Here is html code by which i apply with js in local time.

```
<input type="hidden" class="rest_open_time" value="07:00">
<input type="hidden" class="rest_close_time" value="16:00">
```

And here go jQuery codes by which i detect local time and show a badge is open or closed.But problem is if a shop closes @ 10.00PM It shows open even @ 01.00AM.

```
var open_time = jQuery('.rest_open_time').val();
var close_time = jQuery('.rest_close_time').val();

var x = new Date();
var hours = x.getHours();
var minutes = x.getMinutes();
var time = hours +':'+ minutes;
if (time > open_time && time < close_time){
    jQuery('.rest-stts-badge').addClass('badge-open').append('Open');
}
else{
    jQuery('.rest-stts-badge').addClass('badge-close').append('Closed');
}
```

Comment: We need to see your html to help you out here in the clearest way. However, you will need to remove the `badge-close` class when the restaurant is open, and remove the `badge-open` class when it is closed, in addition to adding the classes that should be there, otherwise, you end up with elements having both classes simultaneously. Look into utilizing `.toggleClass()`

Comment: You're using `>` on a `string` when you should be comparing `numerics`.